# VSTO default setup is not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, ms-word, vsto

I just create a VSTO second edition project for Word AddIn and build the Setup project.

After installed, the error was detected:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant permission to execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131418)


************** Exception Text **************
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant permission to execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131418)
File name: 'WordAddIn1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> System.Security.Policy.PolicyException: Execution permission cannot be acquired.
   at System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Boolean checkExecutionPermission)
   at System.Security.SecurityManager.ResolvePolicy(Evidence evidence, PermissionSet reqdPset, PermissionSet optPset, PermissionSet denyPset, PermissionSet& denied, Int32& securitySpecialFlags, Boolean checkExecutionPermission)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.HandleOnlineOffline(Exception e, String basePath, String filePath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.LoadStartupAssembly(EntryPoint entryPoint, Dependency dependency, Dictionary`2 assembliesHash)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.ConfigureAppDomain()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.LoadAssembliesAndConfigureAppDomain(IHostServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.AppDomainManagerInternal.LoadEntryPointsHelper(IHostServiceProvider serviceProvider)




************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.891
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5456 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5420 (Win7SP1.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common
    Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 8.0.50727.891
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common/8.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5460 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5462 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
```

I changed nothing on the project.

I found some refferences to the SetSecurity C# projects that added as Custon Action on install change this property, but Microsoft site has removed it for download. I found it in a [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79285/Deploying-Office-2003-Solutions-with-Auto-update-F).

I follow the Microsoft tutorial, but an error occurs:
[image: The error!]

Comment: Did you try to run the setup under the context of an admin user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL MUST have permissions grant.

Use the command line in a Custom Action install:

```
caspol -m -q -ag "All_Code" -strong -file "<Full path to DLL>" -noname -noversion  FullTrust -n "<Code group unique name>" -d "<Code group description>"
```

The [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79285/Deploying-Office-2003-Solutions-with-Auto-update-F) code contains errors. To fix, replace the command line above on the call.